# Can't Mount iPhone 5 in Linux - lsusb finds device / no dmesg / ipheth command not found / idevicemount device not found

Tags: linux, usb, mount, iphone

As the title stipulates, I am trying to mount my iPhone 5 in Arch Linux. 

`lsusb` finds the device 
and returns 
`Bus 005 Device 006: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPHone5/5C/5S/6`

`dmesg | grep "Apple"` returns nothing

i have ifuse, libimobiledevice, and usbmuxd installed, but `ipheth` returns `"command not found"`

`idevicepair pair` returns `"No device found, is it plugged in?"`
`ideviceinfo` also returns `"No device found, is it plugged in?"`

Any hints?

Thanks

*EDIT*
`dmesg | grep ipheth`
 returns:

```
   [   20.150489] ipheth 5-6:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
    [   20.150578] usbcore: registered new interface driver ipheth
    [   20.155172] ipheth 5-6:4.2 enp0s29f7u6c4i2: renamed from eth0
```

`lsmod | grep ipheth` returns:

```
ipheth                 16384  0
usbcore               172032  5 uhci_hcd,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,ipheth
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you reinstall all packages ?

// **ifuse libimobiledevice usbmuxd**

To test open two terminals:

terminal1:

```
# usbmuxd -f -v
```

terminal2:

```
# idevicepair pair
# idevicebackup -i backup --full backupdir
```

If working you can enable and start the systemd service:

```
# systemctl enable usbmuxd
# systemctl start usbmuxd
```